# Stop a recursive function Python

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(10)
def bounce(n):
   if n <= 0:
       print(n,)
       bounce(n+1)


   else:
       print(n)
       bounce(n - 1)
       if (n==0 ):
           n==False
```

I'm trying to create a countdown and countup program. I only have the option to use one function and I have to use a recursive function. But every time I run the program it wont do anything the this:

```
4
3
2
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
```

What can I do to make the countup work like it is supposed to? It's supposed to look like this:

```
>>> bounce(4)
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
3
4
>>> bounce(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's good to make a guess at a solution to your problem, but [take care](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) in framing your proposed solution as your question. What you're trying to do is count down, then up, rather than stop recursion. Stopping recursion would require adding `exit()` as your recursive [base case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_case_(recursion)), and this is inappropriate; normal program execution lets the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) resolve naturally (i.e. `return` to its caller). Modifying `sys.setrecursionlimit(10)` isn't recommended, either, because it artificially manipulates a global limit which is easily done with a proper base case conditional.

Here's one approach: print `n` on the way down the recursive call stack, then print `n` on the way back up once your base case has been reached. In other words, each function immediately prints its number, but doesn't print its number a second time until all recursive functions below it have printed their number(s) and resolved.

For example, the first function called, `bounce(4)` prints `4` immediately, then waits for `bounce(3)`, `bounce(2)`, `bounce(1)` and `bounce(0)` to do their work and `return`. That done, `bounce(4)` finally prints `4` once more before returning to the calling scope. All called functions behave the same (`bounce(0)` is a little different; we have to conditionally limit it to a single print to meet the requirement--`if n:` tests whether the number is non-zero).

```
def bounce(n):
    if n >= 0:
        print(n)
        bounce(n - 1)
        
        if n:
            print(n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bounce(4)
```

Output:

```
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
3
4
```

If you're having trouble understanding how the call stack works, try adding indentation to show how deep you are (time increases top to bottom, recursive depth increases left to right).

```
def bounce(n, depth=0):
    if n >= 0:
        print("{}{}".format("  " * depth, n))
        bounce(n - 1, depth + 1)

        if n:
            print("{}{}".format("  " * depth, n))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bounce(4)
```

```
initial call, bounce(4)
|
v
        
4       base case, bounce(0)
  3     |
    2   v
      1
        0
      1  <-- heading back up the call stack, bounce(1)
    2
  3
4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I don't get it how "if n: print n" ,prints out 1,2,3,4?

Comment: Yeah! Thank you . Great explanation!